# How to avoid Google App Engine push queue increased error rates when using named tasks?

Tags: google-app-engine

While reading the documentation for Google App Engine push queues in the Java 8 standard environment, I came across the following information regarding named tasks:

> Note that de-duplication logic introduces significant performance overhead, resulting in increased latencies and potentially increased error rates associated with named tasks.

I would like to utilize the de-duplication logic in a production environment, however, I am concerned about the potentially increased error rates. What is the cause of the increased error rates using named tasks and how can I effectively avoid these issues? Also, when naming the tasks I would use the random 32 character UID of a user as a prefix, therefore the names would not be sequential.

Answer (score 0):

Data de-duplication is a technique for eliminating duplicate copies of repeating data. This can increases the performance needeed by Cloud Tasks in order to eliminate possible duplicate and only dispatch once your request.

If you accidentally add the same task to your list multiple times, the request will still only be dispatched once, avoiding de-duplication.

> In conclusion, when you are using Cloud Tasks, you have a risk of **having higher latencies, which can cause more errors as a result,** like timeout errors for example.

To avoid this kind of errors please also bear in mind the de-duplication window when deleting tasks, as stated [here:](https://cloud.google.com/tasks/docs/quotas)

> The time period during which adding a task with the same name as a recently deleted task will cause the service to reject it with an error. This is the length of time that task de-duplication remains in effect after a task is deleted.